# Change label color from CSS when an input file is enabled or disabled

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="uploadImgParent">
    <label id="uploadImgButton" for="license" class="uploadImgButton">
         Upload
         <input type="file" id="license" accept="image/*"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

I Have this code that show a label (Upload) instead of the standard Button with label for the `input type="file"` (the input is hided by a css, so I can show only the label of Upload).
Now I want that the Background of the label change color when the button is enabled or disabled

The css for the backgrond color now is that:

```
.uploadImgButton{
        color: Black;                   
        background-color: Grey;
        padding: 10px;
        border: double 4px #AAAAAA;
}
```

Now I control it by JS but I want to change the color only by CSS, there is some fast way?
Like:

```
label:enabled{color: red;}  label:disabled{color:grey;}
```

Comment: `when the button is enabled or disabled` can you explain?

Comment: Where is your button?  Do you mean enabled/disabled **input[type=file]**?

Comment: you must use js/jquery because `label` is parent of input and you can apply css to parent according child

Comment: I mean when the input[type=file] is enabled or disabled I want the label to change color.

Example: Enabled: grey - Disabled: red

Comment: simply CSS only is not possible?

Comment: @Wal if you do not want to change the html you must use js if you change the html you can do it by css

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with CSS by using [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), but you'll have to change your layout:

```css
.uploadImgParent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.uploadImgInput {
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* Target labels that goes immediately after ALL inputs */
.uploadImgInput + .uploadImgLabel {
  color: green;
}

/* Target all labels that goes immediately after DISABLED inputs */
.uploadImgInput:disabled + .uploadImgLabel {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="uploadImgParent">
    <input class="uploadImgInput" type="file" id="license1" />
    <label class="uploadImgLabel" for="license1">Upload</label>
</div>

<div class="uploadImgParent">
    <input class="uploadImgInput" type="file" id="license2" disabled />
    <label class="uploadImgLabel" for="license2">Upload</label> 
</div>
```

Comment: .uploadImgInput:disabled + .uploadImgLabel{
This seems doesn't work, problem with the +, the color change only in the button and not the label